# Converting List to QuerySet Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

models.py

```
class Part(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Request(models.Model):
    part_number = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()

class Quota(models.Model):
    part_number = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
```

views.py

```
def requests_and_quotas(request):
    requests = Request.objects.all()
    quotas = Quota.objects.all()
    result = []
    for req in requests:
        match = False
        for quo in quotas:
            if (req.part_number.series == quo.part_number.series) and (abs((req.date - quo.date).days) <= 2):
                result.append({'request': req, 'quota': quo})
        if not match:
            result.append({'request': req, 'quota': None})
    return render(request, 'requests_and_quotas.html', {'result': result,})
```

I wanted to connect django_filters, but ran into a problem AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'. How can I change the logic of my code to retrieve a QuerySet object?

result_qs = QuerySet(result) it didn't help

Comment: can you add the codes related to the django-filters?

Comment: In view - myFilter = RequestFilter(request.GET, queryset=result)
result = myFilter.qs

Comment: class RequestFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ['brand']

Comment: how are you using it in the view, is it the same view or different?

Comment: Not sure if its possible to create a queryset that hold two different model.

Comment: @Brodie121 see my posted answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of ids of your objects in the list. Then simply filter by them.

```
instances = [<MyModel: 1>, <MyModel: 2>]
list_of_ids = [inst.id for inst in instances]
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. But my problem is that I have two models and I want to combine them in one QuerySet

Comment: @Brodie121 two models? Well... Don't :)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge 2 models by appending them in one array and then sort them based on `date` by using Python `chain` itertools

```
from itertools import chain
```

here is the `requests_and_quotas` function

```
def requests_and_quotas(request):
    requests = Request.objects.all()
    quotas = Quota.objects.all()
    queryset = []
    
    queryset.append(requests)
    queryset.append(quotas)
    if len(queryset):
            queryset = sorted(chain(*queryset), reverse=True, key=lambda queryset: queryset.date)
        
    return render(request, 'requests_and_quotas.html', {'queryset': queryset,})
```

then here is how you can decide what will appear in the template based on unique field of the models

```
{% for item in queryset %}
    {% if item.supplier %}
        <!-- here Quota model render -->
    {% else %}
        <!-- here Request model render -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```